# Using serializable yet still getting shallow copy of object

Tags: java, tree, deep-copy

I have browsed the other questions and found solutions as to how to do a deep copy of objects that contain references. I am specifically wanting to make a deep copy of a tree. Logically, each tree node contain references to its children nodes. Here is the basics of my node class

```
public class BSTNode implements Comparable, Serializable  {

    private String token;
    private int count;
    private BSTNode leftChild;
    private BSTNode rightChild;
```

I know I must only be making a shallow copy because when I make a copy of tree1, called tree2, and edit tree1 the edits also appear on tree2. Here is my copy method within my `BSTNode` class

```
public  BSTNode copy()
   {
   BSTNode obj = null;
   try{
       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
       out.writeObject(this);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

       ObjectInputStream in= new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
               bos.toByteArray()));
       obj = (BSTNode) in.readObject();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return obj;
 }
```

When I wish to copy the entire tree, I call that above copy method from my `BSTree` class using the methods below. (I have 2 methods because this is a homework assignment that requires a copy method that calls a preorder traversal method)

```
  public BSTNode copy()
{
    BSTNode copiedTreeRoot = new BSTNode();
    return copyTree(copiedTreeRoot,root);
}

public BSTNode copyTree(BSTNode copiedTreeRoot, BSTNode otherTreeRoot)
{
    if(otherTreeRoot == null)
    {
        copiedTreeRoot = null;
    }
    else
    {
         copiedTreeRoot = otherTreeRoot.copy();
         copyTree(copiedTreeRoot.getLeft(), otherTreeRoot.getLeft());
        copyTree(copiedTreeRoot.getRight(), otherTreeRoot.getRight());          
    }
    return copiedTreeRoot;
}
```

I use these lines to create the new tree and assign the copy to it

```
BSTree tree2 = new BSTree();
tree2.setRoot(tree1.copy());
```

And further along when I make changes to tree1, tree 2 also changes. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I believe it must be somewhere in how I return the new tree or something. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

*EDIT* 
Here is where I call the copy originally. It is in a class of its own that has the main method
     tree2.setRoot(tree1.copy());

It then moves to the `BSTree class` and executes this

```
public BSTNode copy()
{
    //BSTNode copiedTreeRoot = new BSTNode();
   //return copyTree(copiedTreeRoot,root);
    return root.copyTree(root
}
```

The BSTree class has a member element of its root, called `root`
It then bounces to the BSTNode class and executes this

```
 public BSTNode copyTree(BSTNode input)
{
   if(input == null)
   {
       return null;
   }
   else
   {
       BSTNode node = new BSTNode();
       node.token = input.token;
       node.count = input.count;
       node.leftChild = copyTree(input.leftChild);

       node.rightChild = copyTree(input.rightChild);
       System.out.println("node being returned: "+ node.getToken());
       return node;    
   }
```

}

When I go to print the output of the new tree, I get a blank.

Comment: You forget to define a `serialVersionUID` in your `Serializable` classes; this can lead to troubles...

Comment: In your `copy` method on BSTNode, you write out the node, but not its children, although refs to those children are written. Then when you read the node with `copyTree` you get back those refs into your copied version.

Comment: I will admit I have no idea what a `serialVersionUID` is. I am a fairly new programmer and the few times I have used `serializable` i have never come across such a term. Should I just google it? lol

Comment: @deanosaur  Do you have an idea of how to explicitly copy those children? Do I need to recursively call `copy` in BSTNode on the root node's children?

Comment: @deanosaur as my edit shows. It didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     public class BSTNode
{
public String token;
public int count;

public BSTNode leftChild;
public BSTNode rightChild;


public static BSTNode copyTree(BSTNode input){
if(input == null){
return null;
}
else{
BSTNode node = new BSTNode();
node.token = input.token;
node.count = input.count;

node.leftChild = BSTNode.copyTree(input.leftChild);
node.rightChild = BSTNode.copyTree(input.rightChild);
return node;

}

}

public static void main(String args[]){
BSTNode root = new BSTNode();
root.token  = "root";
root.count = 1;

BSTNode leftChild  = new BSTNode();;
leftChild.token  = "left child";
leftChild.count = 2;

root.leftChild = leftChild;

BSTNode copy = copyTree(root);
System.out.println(copy.token);
System.out.println(copy.leftChild.token);

}
}
```

Comment: I love the idea of this solution. The only issue i see is that in your edit of my `copyTree` you call `copyTree(otherTreeRoot.getleft());` and my `copyTree` method as written takes 2 parameters. What should my other one be? Or should I just change the method to take only `BSTNode otherTreeRoot`

Comment: I edited my `copyTree` method to take only the one parameter and created `copiedTreeRoot` as a global variable. That seemed to really create a problem as the copy comes back as blank. I noticed also that you had my add the new copy method into `BSTNode` but never call it

Comment: hi gabriel, i edited my code, i think this should work for you. you can use it like CopiedTree cp = BST.copyTree(rootNodeInput);

Comment: my bad, changed the code again, was wrongly referring to the class name earlier, wanted to refer to the object node

Comment: are you passing the correct reference in getRoot, could you paste the entire code over here

Comment: here is how I use everything:  `tree2.setRoot(tree1.copy()));`   copy in BSTree class has the one line `return root.copyTree(root);`  My copyTree method is then exactly like what you just posted. My get root method is simply `return root`

Comment: ok, are you not using the method i wrote. You should be using BSTNode copiedTreeRoot = copyTree(tree1.getRootNode());

Comment: I went ahead and posted exactly what i'm doing above as an edit. And I cannot do exactly the line you just posted because I am calling `copyTree` from a seperate method. I will try `BSTNode copiedTreeRoot = tree1.getRoot().copyTree(tree1.getRootNode());` because I placed `copyTree` in my BSTNode class

Comment: i have posted the class i am using, with example. Please make the variables private and use appropriate setter/getter, i made them public just so that it'd be easier for me

Comment: Awesome thank you so much for spending this much time on helping me

Comment: So I used your class just like you posted and it is working correctly. Clearly my hours of debugging has corrupted my code somewhere else. I really appreciate your help

Comment: no problem. Also do remember to change the variables to private, they shouldnt be accessible to other classes without proper setter and getter